# RichTextBoxPrintCtrl Printing Issue

Tags: c#, printing

This is my first posting and my programmer status is keen amateur.

I have created a c# Form `RichTextBoxPrintCtrl` editor with print capability via a `printDialog` and `printDocument` control. Before I print I want to determine the page size (based on the number of characters) per print page. The code which calls the `RichTextBoxPrintCtrl dll` to get this info is:

```
checkPrint = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Print(checkPrint, textEnd, e);
```

with e being the `printDocument PrintPageEventArgs`.
The only way I can see to do this appears to be to actually print the document.
Is there a way to capture the `printDocument PrintPageEventArgs` and use them in the above code without actually printing?

The reason I want to do this is to have the ability to use the page from and page to facility within the `printDialog`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful cause I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you override the OnPrintPage() method of the PrintDocument class you can access the same arguments prior to PrintPage() being invoked. If nothing else, you can always capture the PrintPageEventArgs and cancel the print operation by setting e.Cancel to true and returning in OnPrintPage()

Comment: Thanks Glace, even with my limited knowledge this sound like a good approach. However, could you provide an example of how I might do this? Thanks. David